# Safe regex for allowing iframe embed codes, preventing injection

Tags: regex, xss

I'm not so good with regex, but this is what i have so far:

`((<iframe){1}(.+[^script]+[^onload]){1}(><\/iframe>){1}){1}`

the goal is to prevent someone from injecting malicious code to execute with the embed. is this good enough?

feature thus far:

- prevents placing a script tag inside of the iframe tag. prevents
- placing an iefe in onload of iframe.

Comment: I doubt that with non-recursive regex you can prevent malicious attacks. And recursive regex is very limited. I'd rather use something more appropriate for HTML.

Comment: yep, i already found a case where adding onload with anonymous function iefe works.